# Node module generating a lot of subfolders

Tags: node.js, jenkins, directory

I'm running my build on jenkins but when I run `npm install --color=false --loglevel warn` it generate a lot of subfolders, and I can't even delete them on windows (I have to rename them before that).

It has started to happen today, we didin't manually update anything

[image: Node problem]

My packages.json file

```
{
  "name": "contratanet-portal",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Builder do contratanet portal",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-shell": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-msbuild": "~0.1.12",
    "grunt-nuget": "~0.1.3",
    "underscore": "~1.6.0",
    "karma": "^0.12.23",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.1.5",
    "requirejs": "^2.1.15",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.1.4",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^0.1.3",
    "lodash": "^2.4.1",
    "karma-opera-launcher": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-safari-launcher": "^0.1.1",
    "karma-ie-launcher": "^0.1.5",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.1.4",
    "grunt-karma": "^0.9.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, `karma` has a lot of dependencies.  What's your question?

Comment: It's looks like a bug, every dependence has his own module folder, but the problem is  that it frozen the IIS working process and I can't delete it

Comment: It's not a bug.  That's just how deeply nested dependencies work.  Not every dependency has its own folder, many of them are shared. It sounds like something is wrong with your IIS setup if it can't handle a few directories.